# regex to remove ordinals

Tags: regex

I need to remove ordinals via regex, but my regex skills are quite lacking. The following locates the ordinals, but includes the digit just prior in the return value. I need to isolate and remove just the ordinal.

```
[0-9](?:st|nd|rd|th)
```

Comment: There is no regex standard.. Do you want to use it from perl, javascript, csharp or bash ?

Comment: @raj you forgot Java, Python and Erlang amongst others

Comment: @Jarrod Only the languages I was confident I could answer :). Not being a pedant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a [look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) so that only `st|nd|rd|th` preceded by a `[0-9]` are matched, but the `[0-9]` isn't included in the match. i.e.:

```
(?<=[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)
```

I've linked to the perl-compatible syntax, but if you're using posix, posix extended, vi or one of many other regex syntaxes you'll need to look up the syntax.

Comment: Also, the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) have a slightly more wordy explanation if you want more background on the concept (PHP's PCRE functions use the same syntax as Perl).

Comment: Works brilliantly with Ruby. Consider adding case insensitivity to the regexp options so that it matched `85th` as well as `85TH`: `/(?<=[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)/i`.

Answer (score 7):

In perl:

```
$var =~ s{\b(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)\b}{$1};
```

In PHP:

```
$var = preg_replace('/\\b(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)\\b/', '$1', $var);
```

In .NET:

```
var = Regex.Replace(@"\b(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)\b", "$1");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove as well the numbers followed by ordinals you could use this one:

```
[0-9]+(?:st| st|nd| nd|rd| rd|th| th)
```

So for a given text: *"The 3rd person is missing but the 2 nd and the 1st is here"* you'll have this output:
    ***"The  person is missing but the  and the  is here"***

Answer (score 1):

Try a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<=[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)
```

assuming the dialect of regex supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question, because I needed to replace ordinal numbers with dot, i. e. `1.`, `2.`, `4.` etc.

Here is the solution for this problem (in PHP):

`$entry = preg_replace('/^\d+\. /', '', $entry);`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/xLB6Ov/1