# How to Remove Ordinal Values from Date in Java

Tags: java, regex, date, substring, ordinals

I was wondering if anyone knew what the best method was to remove ordinal values in java when you don't know if the input is going to be either a single or double digit number?

i.e.

Input: 23rd

Expected output: 23

---

Input: 1st

Expected output: 1

---

So far, I tried using a combination of the regex util and the substring method:

```
String dayValue = "";
String dayPattern = "(?<=[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)";
Pattern dPattern = Pattern.compile(dayPattern);
Matcher dMatch;

dayValue = "23rd";
dMatch = dPattern.matcher(dayValue);
System.out.println("The Pattern is: " + autoBuyDay.substring(dMatch.start()));
```

But that's just giving me a `No match available error`. Any ideas on how to modify this or a better way to go about accomplishing my goal here?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182290/regex-to-remove-ordinals

Comment: But that seems to work with php and ruby, maybe not with Java...

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but I didn't see any java specific examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputString.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Will remove all non-digit characters from the string.

Comment: this will remove separators too, like '-' or '.' or '/'... or months expressed with words

Comment: @Aurand That seems to have worked great. Definitely much easier than the route I was going down haha. Thank you very much. Would still be curious to see how you'd do that with regex in java, but that's not really a priority anymore.

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer - This answer **does** use a regex in java.

Comment: Ah I see it now, was over thinking it in my head. My apologies.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: To avoid that you would merely replace the `\D` with `[^\d-/]` (add whatever characters you want to keep into that character class)