# How to remove ordinal value in Java?

Tags: java, string-matching, ordinals

I have Station Names like `23 St, 21 St` in our **mysql** database.

I am applying **Lucene** Algorithm to search the stations in **Java**.

For **23 St** user can give inputs like **23rd St, 23rd** etc.

I want to remove Ordinals from the given inputs, like if user gives **23rd St** then I want it to replace with **23 St**.

So is there any way to remove ordinal value in Java?

Comment: Did you try `String.replace(<some regex>)` ?

Comment: Look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182290/regex-to-remove-ordinals

Comment: @Apurv I tried with String.replace but it gives only numbers from complete String like 23rd St output = 23

Comment: @Deepu Use the regex from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182290/regex-to-remove-ordinals) provided by Colin with the `String.replace()` function.

Comment: Many Thanks to @Apurv, I used the method as you said, **inputString.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)", "")**, and I got the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove ordinals:

```
String s = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(rd|st|nd|th)\\b", "");
```

Comment: Doesn't specify number so "1st August" becomes "1 Augu".

Comment: @greg Right error, wrong reason... it does specify number: `(?<=\\d)` is a *look behind*, which asserts (ie requires) the preceding character to be a digit. However, my syntax was off. I've fixed it. See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/cRp9mRfVDr). Nice pick up.