# How to remove Date Ordinals (st, nd, rd, th)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm unable to find a way to remove date ordinals while preserving the month in a string.

For example, I would need:

> June 12th, 2015

To output to:

> June 12, 2015

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182290/regex-to-remove-ordinals) that mentions how to do it, but that form of RegEx does not work with JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using moments library?

Comment: Use `.replace(/(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)/, "$1")`

Comment: Is the input always just a date, or could it be an entire sentence that happened to contain a date?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create two capturing group, to select both the number of month `(\d+)` and its ordinal `(st|nd|rd|th)`. Then replace the string with `$1` *(first group which is containing the number of month)*. Something like this:

```
var str = "June 12th, 2015";
str.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/, "$1");
//=> June 12, 2015
```

### [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN4oG0/1)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use RegEx:

```
ord_day_pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)")
print re.compile(ord_day_pattern).sub("", mystring)
```

One-liner:

```
print re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)").sub("", mystring)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to worry about the various ordinals you could use a regex to match any 2 characters preceding a `,`. The regex to use would be:

```
var regex= /[a-z]{2},/;
```

which matches a string of 2 characters followed by a `,`.

For example:

```
> var regex= /[a-z]{2},/;
> var dateStr = 'June 12th, 2015';
> dateStr.replace(regex, ',');
< 'June 12, 2015'
```